# user auth is_active false flag not working in Django

Tags: python, django

I am using is_active flag is equal to false in views.py so non-superusers can log in also but that is not working. Only superuser is able to log in.

Here are some codes

Login logic view:

```
def logingin(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username','')
        password = request.POST.get('password','')
        user = auth.authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('/')     
        else:
            return redirect('/signup')

    return render(request, 'login.html')
```

signup logic view

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_name = request.POST.get('user_name','')
        first_name = request.POST.get('first_name','')
        last_name = request.POST.get('last_name','')
        email = request.POST.get('email','')
        password = request.POST.get('password','')
        if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            messages.error(request, 'E-Mail Already Exist Please Use Different Email')
        else:    
            user = User.objects.create_user(user_name, email, password)
            user.is_active = False
            user.first_name = first_name
            user.last_name = last_name
            user.save()
    return render(request, 'signup.html')
```

I expect that all user can log in through

Comment: Unrelated, but your __REALLY__ want to use django forms - directly using unvalidated unsanitized request data like you're doing here is a major security issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[By definition](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_active), the `is_active` flag is used to prevent users from logging in. If you want all users to be able to log in, don't set it to false.

Comment: so what should I do now? if I set it true the same problem is there.

Comment: @mohitchandel what about doing the official tutorial and reading the doc ? Looks like it would be a good start and could save you a _whole_ lot of pain and troubles.

Comment: Agree 100%. I could tell you to check your authentication backends, for instance, and that could potentially be the issue here, but it would only mean you'll run into other problems shortly if you blindly follow our advice and don't invest some time beforehand studying the Django tutorial and docs.

Answer (score 0):

> Set is_active=True

if you are setting is_active to flag then you mean that user is disabled. Disabling user help if we don't want user to delete from our database and to respect foreign key constraint.

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_name = request.POST.get('user_name','')
        first_name = request.POST.get('first_name','')
        last_name = request.POST.get('last_name','')
        email = request.POST.get('email','')
        password = request.POST.get('password','')
        if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            messages.error(request, 'E-Mail Already Exist Please Use Different Email')
        else:    
            user = User.objects.create_user(user_name, email, password)
            user.is_active = True
            user.first_name = first_name
            user.last_name = last_name
            user.save()
    return render(request, 'signup.html')
```

Comment: That is not helpful too

Comment: trying creating a new user not existing user

Comment: I've created a new user successfully but not able to login with that user info. But if I fill the details of superuser then logic runs successfully

Comment: check in db whether is_active is set to True or not.......https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Authentication

Comment: is_active is True in db